# Java Gson parse Json object to array

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I'm trying to parse the below Json using the Gson lib in Java. When using other languages, such as C#, this JSON is parsed into an array, however it seems Gson converts this into a set of java attributes (which to be honest, makes more sense to me). Does anyone know if I can change this behaviour of the Gson lib?

```
{
  "Outer": {
    "0": {
      "Attr1": 12345,
      "Attr2": 67890
    },
    "1": {
      "Attr1": 54321,
      "Attr2": 09876
    }
  }
}
```

The below code demonstrates how Gson parses the array as a JsonObject. To be clear, I realise I've referenced `outer` as a `JsonObject` but I was just doing this to demonstrate the code. If I try and reference `outer` as an `JsonArray`, the code fails.

```
String json = "{\"Outer\": { \"0\": { \"Attr1\": 12345, \"Attr2\": 67890 }, \"1\": { \"Attr1\": 54321, \"Attr2\": 09876 }}}";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .setLenient()
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();

JsonObject jo = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
JsonObject outer = jo.getAsJsonObject("Outer");

System.out.println(outer);
System.out.println(outer.isJsonArray());
```

Result:

```
{"0":{"Attr1":12345,"Attr2":67890},"1":{"Attr1":54321,"Attr2":"09876"}}
false
```

//edit
I'm using this current simple Json as an example, however my application of this code will be to parse Json that's of varying and unknown shape. I therefore need Gson to automatically parse this to an array so that the `isJsonArray` returns `true`.

Comment: Actually, your JSON is not an array, it is an array inside an object. What do isJsonArray() return with String json = "\"[Outer\": { \ [...] }] ?

Comment: That would be an array. I am told that the above example would be parsed to an array by JavaScript and a c# lib and I'm trying to replicate that behaviour in java with Gson.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you but as fas as I understand Js doesn't parse your example json into an arry but into an object with two parameters: https://imgur.com/vxL043G

Comment: I agree @CarlosLópezMarí, but apparently JavaScript and c# parses this as an array, which I was trying to mimic in Java.

Comment: The image I peasted is from Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** See "Using Deserializer" section at the bottom for parsing straight to array.

---

That JSON does not contain any arrays. An array would use the `[...]` JSON syntax.

Normally, a JSON object would map to a POJO, with the `name` in the name/value pairs mapping to a field of the POJO.

However, a JSON object can also be mapped to a `Map`, which is especially useful when the names are dynamic, since POJO fields are static.

#### Using Map

The JSON object with numeric values as names can be mapped to a `Map<Integer, ?>`, e.g. to parse that JSON to POJOs, do it like this:

```
class Root {
    @SerializedName("Outer")
    public Map<Integer, Outer> outer;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Root[outer=" + this.outer + "]";
    }
}
```

```
class Outer {
    @SerializedName("Attr1")
    public int attr1;
    @SerializedName("Attr2")
    public int attr2;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Outer[attr1=" + this.attr1 + ", attr2=" + this.attr2 + "]";
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Root root;
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.json"))) {
    root = gson.fromJson(in, Root.class);
}
System.out.println(root);
```

*Output*

```
Root[outer={0=Outer[attr1=12345, attr2=67890], 1=Outer[attr1=54321, attr2=9876]}]
```

---

#### Get as Array

You can then add a helper method to the `Root` class to get that as an array:

```
public Outer[] getOuterAsArray() {
    if (this.outer == null)
        return null;
    if (this.outer.isEmpty())
        return new Outer[0];
    int maxKey = this.outer.keySet().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().getAsInt();
    Outer[] arr = new Outer[maxKey + 1];
    this.outer.forEach((k, v) -> arr[k] = v);
    return arr;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(root.getOuterAsArray()));
```

*Output*

```
[Outer[attr1=12345, attr2=67890], Outer[attr1=54321, attr2=9876]]
```

---

#### Using Deserializer

However, it would likely be more useful if the conversion to array is done while parsing, so you need to write a `JsonDeserializer` and tell Gson about it using `@JsonAdapter`:

```
class Root {
    @SerializedName("Outer")
    @JsonAdapter(OuterArrayDeserializer.class)
    public Outer[] outer;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Root[outer=" + Arrays.toString(this.outer) + "]";
    }
}
```

```
class OuterArrayDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Outer[]> {
    @Override
    public Outer[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // Parse JSON array normally
        if (json.isJsonArray())
            return context.deserialize(json, Outer[].class);

        // Parse JSON object using names as array indexes
        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        if (obj.size() == 0)
            return new Outer[0];
        int maxKey = obj.keySet().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().getAsInt();
        Outer[] arr = new Outer[maxKey + 1];
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> e : obj.entrySet())
            arr[Integer.parseInt(e.getKey())] = context.deserialize(e.getValue(), Outer.class);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Same `Outer` class and test code as above.

*Output*

```
Root[outer=[Outer[attr1=12345, attr2=67890], Outer[attr1=54321, attr2=9876]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll asume your `JsonObject` is a POJO class such like:

`public Inner[] outer;`

If you want an array of objects you can change your code to:

```
Inner[] jo = gson.fromJson(json, Inner[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I've updated my post to try and explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code
1.To get an array of Objects (outerArray)
2.You can extract a `JsonArray` (outerJsonArray) containing values of inner objects in `Outer` (in case keys aren't significant for further use)

```java
String json = "{\"Outer\": { \"0\": { \"Attr1\": 12345, \"Attr2\": 67890 }, \"1\": { \"Attr1\": 54321, \"Attr2\": 09876 }}}";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().setLenient().serializeNulls().create();
JsonObject jo = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
JsonObject outer = jo.getAsJsonObject("Outer");

Object[] outerArray = outer.entrySet().toArray();
// outerArray: [0={"Attr1":12345,"Attr2":67890}, 1={"Attr1":54321,"Attr2":"09876"}]

JsonArray outerJsonArray = new JsonArray();
outer.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
outerJsonArray.add(outer.get(key));
});
//jsonArray=[{"Attr1":12345,"Attr2":67890},{"Attr1":54321,"Attr2":"09876"}]

System.out.println(outer);
System.out.println(outerJsonArray.isJsonArray() + " " + outerJsonArray);
```

Comment: Thanks tir0w. Unfortunately, I don't know the shape of the JSON that I'll be parsing so I can't write code specifically for a case. I need a way to understand if the above 'array' scenario is happening in an unknown shaped JSON file. eg. the attribute "outer" may not exist, or could be at another level. I currently rely on isJsonArray to determine if it's an array and its the behaviour of this function that I'm trying to change.

Comment: @JAC2703, well, it's not an array, that's why you are not getting an array. I think your approach is correct but yoir example isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jackson – Marshall String to JsonNode will be useful in your case.with following pom:- 


    //POM FILE


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

//JAVA CODE
    //read json file data to String


     byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("employee.txt"));

        //create ObjectMapper instance
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //read JSON like DOM Parser
        JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
        JsonNode idNode = rootNode.path("id");
        System.out.println("id = "+idNode.asInt());

        JsonNode phoneNosNode = rootNode.path("phoneNumbers");
        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = phoneNosNode.elements();
        while(elements.hasNext()){
            JsonNode phone = elements.next();
            System.out.println("Phone No = "+phone.asLong());
        }
```

**You can use the JsonNode class's method findParent findValue and findPath which reduce your code as compare to another parsing library.**